# Google game service information

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I have different questions and I don't know who to ask so I'm here. I have a Google Developer account  and in the developer console I can see the part for the game service.  My question is free to use them (such as same scores and other service ) or I have to pay google for use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! there is no additional charge to use once you have your Play account.  The overview of Game Services is here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

The only caveat to being "no additional charge" is that there is a quota limit for free access, details: https://developers.google.com/games/services/quota